# Microsoft Access: How to create a single report with multiple totals rows (totaling based on date)

Tags: excel, ms-access, ms-office

I am very new to microsoft access. I work in an Immunization program where I routinely collect data about vaccinated children. I used to have excel spreadsheets (different spreadsheet for every campaign) but as the number of spreadsheets grew, comparison between data of different campaigns became difficult.

Now I am trying to get all the data into a database program in which I can bring data from multiple campaigns into a single report easily.
After jumping into access, first I need to get the basic things done that excel could do very easily. e.g.

[image: sample data day 1]
[image: sample data day 2]

This is sample data from day 1 and day 2 of the campaign. In access I can create a query which shows data from day 1 only and a totals row at the end. But how do I create a single query/report which shows separate totals row for each day. In other words, how do I reproduce the data in pictures above in a single access report.

Edit:

I am planning a single table that contains data from all the campaigns in various columns.
The table in microsoft access looks like this:
[image: access table]
[image: access table]

Link to the access database file:
[link to access database file](https://uploadfiles.io/ivtwn)

Comment: shall we speak about table definitions before query and the output? post your current table definition. that might help

Comment: This sounds like one of the most basic totals (grouped aggregate) queries, but as krish KM said, you're not providing your table structure. Also, you may be a beginner, but we do expect [lots of research, even from beginners](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: In addition to table definitions, you need to think about defining a primary key which will link your data from multiple campaigns.

Comment: I have posted some screenshots and a link to the entire sample database file.

Comment: Use report Sorting & Grouping features with aggregate calcs in group header or footer section.

Answer (score 0):

June7 has provided the correct advice - though it is cryptic.

Your table structure appears correct - you want a single table with the identity of the campaign and date (or whatever parameters you seek to differentiate them).

Your query is to collect those records into a record set.  (Although there is an aggregate query type - it is not meant for what you seek to do.)  You don't want to report on the entire database each time probably so one uses a query rather than the table itself to be the record set of the report.  How that query is delimited is up to you.

The report object is where one then groups - and a group can have a total.  You will want to look into online/text instructions on this for actual implementation.